# Where to find company's timezone?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

We need timezone in order to sync data.  There is no such a data in CompanyInfo nor in Preferences:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/companyinfo
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/preferences

It is strange since there is field called `DefaultTimeZone` in `Company` class in the C# API provided by Intuit.  Sadly this field comes back empty from the request.

Is there any other way to get timezone for the account?

Comment: Many companies have offices/branches/stores/whatever in many different time zones. What would the time zone for such a company be? There may not even be a well-defined headquarters or home office or ...

Comment: Timezone which is used to book transactions, mark bills as paid and so.